# "flexDirection: row" is not working with contentContainerStyle in FlatList which is rendering inside another FlatList?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

If the secondFlatlist rendering directly, it will be result in this.

[image]

If secondFlatlist rendering inside another flatList, the flexDirection: row can't apply.

[image]

How to display "one", "two", "three" in a row inside a FlatList?

My code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, FlatList } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {

  const SecondFlatlist = () => (
    <FlatList
      data={["one","two","three"]}
      renderItem={ ({item, index}) => (
        <Text>{item}</Text>
      )}
      keyExtractor={ value => value }
      contentContainerStyle={{
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        margin: 10,
      }}
    />
  )

  return (
    <View style={{
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignContent: 'flex-start',
      backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
      padding: 8,
    }}>
      <Text>Hope</Text>
      <SecondFlatlist />
      <Text>Hope</Text>
      <SecondFlatlist />
      <Text>Hope</Text>
      <SecondFlatlist />

      <FlatList
        data={["Poor","Bad","Good"]}
        renderItem={ ({item, index}) => (
          <>
            <Text>{item}</Text>
            <SecondFlatlist />
          </>
        )}
        keyExtractor={ value => value }
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try adding `horizontal: true` for the second 'Flatlist'?

Check the documentation here:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#horizontal

Comment: Thank you very much. This work with `justifyContent: 'space-between'` when adding `flex: 1` in the contentContainerStyle of SecondFlatList.

Comment: If my answer was helpful and was able to resolve your issue, then please consider marking it as the accepted answer.